# Google Drive SDK JS file upload and download(access content)

Tags: javascript, json, google-drive-api, dropbox

Using javascript,

1. I want my users to upload a `txt/json` file to their `google drive account`.
2. I want a chooser like in `dropbox` of file browse which will allow the user to access their `Google Drive` and they will choose this `txt/json` file and I want to access the contents of this file in my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this via the [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/)

Just configure it to only show files of type txt/json.